# Using applescript to change stroke weights conditionally in Illustrator CS6

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

I was trying to use this code.

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    tell front document
        set properties of every path item whose stroke weight is less than 0.2 to {stroke width:0.2}
    end tell
end tell
```

I see no reason why it shouldn't work, but it gets hung up on the phrase "path item." I don't understand what else I should do! I'm trying to get this to work in Illustrator CS6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm doing this on CS4, but it really should be the same, although I suppose it is possible (unlikely) that "**stroke width**" changed to "stroke weight". I think you also need to **specify the layer**. Try something like (of course you'll have to specify the correct layer) this; it works for me:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    tell front document
        set stroke width of (every path item of layer 1 of it whose stroke width is less than 0.2) to 0.2
    end tell
end tell
```